# excel spreadsheet import/export issue in R

Tags: r, excel, xls

I have an excel file with the first column completely blank. When i read it into R using read.xls the first column does not appear. However, when I export the data set, that column reappears but with numbers in it corresponding to the row.

My issue is that I do need my expoted xls sheet to retain that first blank column (including **no** header/variable name).

How do I retain that column or make sure the exported spreadsheet has it?

Comment: Did you take a look at the function arguments?

Comment: would colIndex work? is that the suggestion.